# Display most recent date for out status

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure this out.  I have a query that will display IN and Out Status and Datetime in two separate columns(originally in same column).  The query will return the results the way I need them but the OUT dates are displaying incorrectly.  Each ID has multiple In/Out statuses and times.  I only need the latest In/out time within the last 24 hours.  The query will return the In times correctly, but a lot of the Out times are showing dates earlier than the In times. So what I need to see is, the OUT times within the last 24 hours and if a user hasn't checked out it should be blank. Can someone please help me with this? See code below.

```
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.FNAME, t1.InOut_Status AS Status_In, t1.Datetime AS
Datetime_IN, t2.InOut_Status AS Status_Out, t2.Datetime As Datetime_OUT
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
    AND t2.InOut_Status = 'OUT' AND t1.Datetime >= DATEADD(hour, -24,GETDATE())
WHERE t1.InOut_Status = 'IN'
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with a derived table.

```
...
LEFT JOIN 
    (select t.id, max(t.Datetime) dt
     from table t
     group by t.id
     where t.InOut_Status = 'OUT'
     AND t.Datetime >= DATEADD(hour, -24,GETDATE())) t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT ID,
       FNAME,
       MAX(CASE
               WHEN InOut_Status = 'IN'
               THEN Datetime
           END) AS Datetime_IN,
       MAX(CASE
               WHEN InOut_Status = 'OUT'
               THEN Datetime
           END) AS Datetime_OUT
FROM   [Table]
WHERE  Datetime >= DATEADD(hour, -24, GETDATE())
GROUP BY ID,
         FNAME
```